# I'm having trouble displaying an image multiple times with a for loop

Tags: javascript, image, for-loop

I'm having trouble displaying an image multiple times with JavaScript. I created this application (for practice purposes) that takes input from the user and displays an image a number of times based on the input it has received from the user. The problem here is that it never displays a single image for some reason.
Google chrome doesn't show any errors. I'm assuming that it's a logic error.
Can someone please help me?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style media="screen">
    img, li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    input, div {
      display: block;
      margin: 2rem 0 0;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>List Of Google Images</h1>
    <ul id="imageList"></ul>.
    <div class="">
      <label for="displayImage">Display Image</label>
      <select class="" name="selector" id="numberSelector">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
      </select>
      <label for="displayImage2">Times</label>

      <input type="button" name="" value="Go" id="go">
    </div>

  </main>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  }
  var displayImages = function() {
    var pictures = "";
    var numberSelector = $("numberSelector").value;
    numberSelector = parseInt(numberSelector);
    var imageList = "<li><img src='https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2021/st-patricks-day-2021-6753651837108887.2-l.png'></li>";
    var i = 0;
    for (i < numberSelector; i++;) {
      pictures = pictures + imageList;
    }
    $("imageList").innerHTML = pictures;
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    $("go").onclick = displayImages;
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `for` statement is wrong. Should be `for (let i = 0; i < numberSelector; i++)`

Comment: @LilDevil Thanks!